# ELI5 how does React Hooks know when to update the DOM?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've read [Hooks at a Glance](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) and I understood why:

1. Hooks can be declared only at the top level
2. Hooks names should start with `use`

But they don't talk about how the render engine gets updated. Is it the same as with classes? If yes, how do they "bind" the state and trigger a DOM update?

Comment: Clarification: Hooks can only be _called_ at the "top level", which is to say, _unconditionally_, in a _deterministic_ order a _constant_ amount of times, either within a component, or another hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article by Dan Abramov: [overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do](https://overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do). As he states in it:

> "When people first look at the Hooks proposal API, they often wonder:
>   how does useState “know what to do”? The assumption is that it’s more
>   “magical” than a base React.Component class with this.setState(). But
>   as we have seen today, the base class setState() implementation has
>   been an illusion all along. It doesn’t do anything except forwarding
>   the call to the current renderer. And useState Hook does exactly the
>   same thing."

Comment: Thank you for this, but the question is about React's underlying mechanism that binds the state to the DOM.

Comment: I changed the answer to try and better fit your question